# UNION(NOT UNION ALL) - What does this mean?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out this driving query.

UNION(NOT UNION ALL) does not work in Oracle SQL, how do it rewrite it so it works in Oracle?

The query structure is like this:

```
select KEY, CODE from table1
where IND = '1'
UNION(NOT UNION ALL)
select CODE, ORG_CODE from table2
join ORG on KEY = KEY
join REGION on KEY = KEY
```

Comment: I think the person who wrote that meant to say you should just use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would just write:

```
select KEY, CODE
from table1
where IND = '1'
UNION -- NOT UNION ALL
select CODE, ORG_CODE
from table2 join
     ORG
     on KEY = KEY join
     REGION
     on KEY = KEY;
```

The intention of the code is highlight that `UNION` is intended.  `UNION` incurs extra overhead for removing duplicates.  So, under normal circumstances, you should use `UNION ALL`.  The comment makes it explicit that duplicate removal is intended.

(Note:  The query has other problems, such as the `JOIN` conditions.  I assume this is just a transcription issue in the question.)